# Running Docker Container in Host Mode Causes Networking Problems For Dependent Containers

Tags: networking, docker-compose, rpc, bitcoin

I'm trying to install [this service](https://github.com/bitfeed-project/bitfeed) to run a visualizer on bitcoin's blockchain. The application itself isn't so important; the key point is that I'm trying to point it to my bitcoin RPC service that's running on the local host, not in another docker container. As such, I need to run the "api" service in host networking mode.

The problem is, when I do that, it seems to break nginx somewhere in the application stack. The following error is from the logs in my "web" container (docker-compose.yml is below for reference)

```
2023/03/03 22:22:54 [emerg] 1#1: host not found in upstream "api:6000" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:42
nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream "api:6000" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:42
```

For the life of me I can't figure it out. When I take the "api" service off of host networking mode, suddenly the error above stops being thrown by my "web" container. But if I do that, the "api" container obviously is not able to connect to the bitcoin RPC service on localhost.

Any pointers on how to make this work would be very much appreciated!

My docker-compose file is:

```
version: "3"

services:
  web:
    image: ghcr.io/bitfeed-project/bitfeed-client:v2.3.4
    restart: on-failure
    stop_grace_period: 1m
    depends_on:
      - api
    environment:
      TARGET: docker
      BACKEND_HOST: api
      BACKEND_PORT: "6000" #modified because port 5000 is already in use by another service
    ports:
      - "3080:80" #modified because port 3000 is already in use by another service

  api:
    image: ghcr.io/bitfeed-project/bitfeed-server:v2.3.4
    user: "1000:1000"
    restart: on-failure
    stop_grace_period: 1m
    network_mode: host #added network_mode: host so that I can access bitcoin RPC on local machine
    environment:
      PORT: "6000" #modified because port 5000 is already in use by another service
      BITCOIN_HOST: "127.0.0.1" #modified to point to localhost
      BITCOIN_ZMQ_RAWBLOCK_PORT: 28332
      BITCOIN_ZMQ_RAWTX_PORT: 28333
      BITCOIN_ZMQ_SEQUENCE_PORT: 28334
      BITCOIN_RPC_PORT: 8332
      BITCOIN_RPC_USER: raspibolt
      BITCOIN_RPC_PASS: [password]
```

Tried:

1. Changing ports (no effect)
2. Running "api" service in bridge mode (can't connect to bitcoin RPC service on localhost this way)
3. Attempting to modify `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf` in the "web" service container (confusingly, the expected value of "api:6000" already appears to be there)

Expected result: the API connects to the bitcoin RPC back end and synchronizes mempool; the web service then connects to the API on port 5000 and the web app becomes accessible at localhost:3080

Actual result: the API connects to the bitcoin RPC back end and synchronizes mempool; the web service keeps dying because "api:6000" is expected as an upstream value in `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf` but is not found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to:

1. Specify `network_mode: host` for both `web` and `api` services. Note that port mapping is incompatible with network mode host. It means that `web` service will try to use your `127.0.0.1:80`. Make sure port 80 is available or make `web` use some other port;
2. Make the `web` service look for the API at `127.0.0.1:6000` instead of `api:6000`. You should be able to achieve this by modifying the `web`'s `BACKEND_HOST` env variable in `docker-compose.yml` if I understand correctly.

Explanation: for all 3 pieces to communicate well they should be on the same network. You have 2 options: host or docker bridge. If you don't want to dockerize your RPC bitcoin service and make it a part of `docker-compose` you are left with the option to deploy `web` and `api` services in the host network. When you do it, `api` is no longer available at `api:6000` because it's the bridge network address. Instead, it becomes available at the host network, hence `127.0.0.1:6000`.

Comment: Thanks! that's super helpful. I made the change and now the "web" service starts, which is excellent! But I'm still unable to access the application at 127.0.0.1:84 (the new port I defined). I also tried creating a rule in nginx on the local host to expose port 3080 to 84 locally, and made sure those ports were open on my firewall. My updated docker-compose is here... do you see a glaring omission, or do I still need to do something on my host machine to get this working? https://gist.github.com/TheFockinFury/fd6f6a5fc2d322646125b72b0872ff4c

Comment: @TheFury the `ports` block doesn't work if you use the host network, it loses its meaning. You should be able to reach `web`  at `127.0.0.1:80` (make sure 80 isn't used by some other program, otherwise `web` will fail). Port 80 is what this container uses by default. If you want to change that, you don't use `ports` in docker-compose, you have to modify the `web`'s nginx config.

Comment: Ok, thanks again. I see that now. Slightly annoying to have to fix nginx configs every time I update the container, but I'm willing to pay that price!

Last question then... rather than running "api" in host mode, is there any way I could make this work by adding an extra_host of "host.docker.internal:host-gateway?" Or am I required to use host mode for the container in this case? From what I read it seems like this should work but I'm likely missing something.

Comment: @TheFury you could try doing the `extra_host` thing. You'd need to revert the `network_mode: host` change and set `api`'s  `BITCOIN_HOST=host.docker.internal`.

Comment: @TheFury to avoid having to change nginx config every time you recreate the container you can create the config file locally and then use Docker volumes to overwrite the container's default config.